# Phase shift in numpy gradient when computing derivative of Cosine

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I tried simply to calculate the derivative of a Cosine with numpy function 'gradient'. The result should be a sine, however if I do it with the following very simple code, my result is a sine with phase shift pi!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,120)
y = np.cos(x)

deriv = np.gradient(y,(2*np.pi/120))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,deriv)
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?
I need to calculate the derivative of some data for some calculations, and I expect the derivative to be the source of an error I try to solve for a while now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The derivative of cos(x) is -sin(x) (which is also a phase-shifted sine thanks to periodicity) so if that's what you are observing then it seems OK to me

Comment: Oh yes, I see it now! Thank you!